# access violation exception with 12c

Tags: c#, oracle, access-violation, odp.net, oracle12c

We were using Oracle 11g 64 bit odp client to connect to 11g database. We have recently upgraded to Oracle 12c. I have uninstalled 11g odp client in my local machine(Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit). I made sure that the registry entries are deleted from `regedit.exe`. After installing Oracle 12c 64 bit, I can successfully establish a connection. But after a commit when I try closing the connection using `OracleConnection.close()` I am getting

> "AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt".

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Professional as IDE. Please let me know
 how to resolve this issue. Below is the stack trace for the exception:

> at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OpsCon.Close(IntPtr& opsConCtx, IntPtr&
>   opsErrCtx, OpoConValCtx* pOpoConValCtx, OpoConRefCtx pOpoConRefCtx)
>   at
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.ConnectionPool.CheckLifeTimeAndStatus(OpoConCtx&
>   opoConCtx, Boolean bDistTxnActive, Boolean& bClosed, Int32 bFromPool,
>   Boolean bCheckLifetimeOnly, Boolean bFreeValCtxOnDispose, Boolean
>   isPopulatePool)    at
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.ConnectionPool.PutConnection(OpoConCtx&
>   opoConCtx, Boolean bDoNotAllocValCtx, Boolean bCheckStatus, Boolean
>   bCheckLifeTime, Int32 bDistTxnActive, Boolean isPopulatePool, Boolean
>   bFreeValCtxOnDispose)    at
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.ConnectionDispenser.Close(OpoConCtx&
>   opoConCtx, Boolean isContextConnection)    at
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Close()

Comment: Do a search on your machine for oci.dll. It is part of the many other Oracle Client DLLs. If you find it delete/rename all the other Oracle DLLs you find in that location. It is possible some old client DLLs got left behind in unexpected places and are being loaded and are mismatched,

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue arise in some builds of the ODP.NET client, specifically the unmanaged 64-bit version.

For what I was able to debug, disassemble, diagnose, etc. this is a bug in the ODP.NET client assemblies. I haven't seen it recently in our tooling any more, so maybe you could upgrade to the latest version if you didn't do that already.

Comment: Which version of Oracle client are you using?

Comment: I am using `Version=2.121.2.0` That would be 12.1.2.0. Usually I used the managed version, which has some bugs too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems issue exists with Oracle.DataAccess(4.121.2.0). We installed older version of 12c which gives 4.121.1.0 version of Oracle.DataAccess.dll. It resolved the issue.